# Computing length of a string around a rod

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

A string is wound symmetrically around a circular rod. The string goes exactly 4 times around the rod. The circumference of the rod is 4 cm. and its length is 12 cm. Find the length of the string.

I use $r(t)= \left(\frac{2}{\pi}\cos\left(\frac{3t}{2\pi}\right),\frac{2}{\pi}\sin\left(\frac{3t}{2\pi}\right),t\right)$.

Note: $2/\pi$ accounts for the radius, and the arguments of $\sin$ and $\cos$ account for the period.

Then, I integrate $\int_0^{8\pi}||r'(t)||dt$, which does not produce the desired answer (20 cm).

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: $r(8\pi)=\left(2\cos(12)/\pi,2\sin(12)/\pi,8\pi\right)$ which is not where the string should finish, it should finish at $(2,0,12)$ shouldn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure where it should finish  -- I thought $(0,0,12)$ is the desired point. I tried using the general form of a helix and then modifying it to the problem.

Comment: It can't end at $(0,0,12)$, because that's on the axis of the rod. Seeing that you found the rod's radius to be $\frac2\pi$, I think you wanted $(\frac2\pi,0,12)$.

Comment: So, what would $r(t)$ be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by DJohnM (using an "unrolled" cylinder to visualize the path length)
is possibly the easiest way to solve this, and does not require you to take
the magnitude of a derivative of a vector.

But if you want to use the general method you started with, choose a
consistent parameterization of the helix. If you want the last coordinate
of $r(t)$ to be $t$, as shown in your formula for $r(t)$, then you should
be integrating from $t = 0$ to $t = 12$ (starting at one end of the rod
and ending at the other), and you should adjust the coefficients
inside your sine and cosine functions so that at $t = 12$ you
are taking $\cos(8\pi)$ and $\sin(8\pi)$ -- that is, you should have
made exactly four "wraps" between $t = 0$ to $t = 12$.

On the other hand, if you want to integrate from $t = 0$ to $t = 8\pi$,
parameterizing by the direction from the axis (an angle),
then you should make the last coordinate of $r(t)$ equal to $12$
when $t = 8\pi$. That suggests the last coordinate should be
something like $kt$ where $k\neq1$.

Comment: I found two integrals and one works out to the right answer but the other doesn't, and I'm not sure why. The integrals are $\int_0^{8\pi} \sqrt{1+(\frac{3}{\pi^2}\sin(\frac{3}{2\pi}))^2+\frac{3}{2\pi^2}\cos(\frac{3t}{2‌​\pi)))^2)}dt$

Comment: The first integral is (this one does not work) $\int_0^{8\pi} \sqrt{1+(\frac{3}{\pi^2}\sin(\frac{3}{2\pi}))^2+(\frac{3}{\pi^2}\cos(\frac{3t}{2\pi}))^2}dt$
and the second one is $\int_0^{12} \sqrt{1+(\frac{4}{3}\sin(\frac{2\pi t}{3}))^2+(\frac{4}{3}\cos(\frac{2\pi t}{3}))^2}dt$
which correctly evaluates to 20 cm

Comment: @Guest23 In the first integral, $t$ is the angle of wrapping around the axis, so you want to use functions like $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$, that is, simple trig functions of the angle $t$ itself, not multiplying $t$ by some other number like in $\sin(2\pi t/3)$.

Comment: So, why did the second integral work then?

Comment: In the second integral, $t$ is the distance along the rod. The angle is not equal to the distance. To put it another way, no matter how you integrate, the angle has to "wrap" exactly four times, so if you have $\sin(0)$ in the formula when $t$ is at the lower bound of integration, you must have $\sin(8\pi)$ at the upper bound of integration. If the integration goes to $12$ you need $\sin(2\pi t/3)$ because $8\pi = 2\pi(12)/3$. If the integration goes to $8\pi$ then you need $\sin(t)$.

Comment: Thanks for the continued help. I think I understand what you are saying now. The integral $\int_0^{8\pi} \sqrt{1+[\frac{2}{\pi}\sin(t)]^2+[\frac{2}{\pi}\cos(t)]^2}dt$ should be calculating the wrap four times around but the result is about 29. Is there something I'm missing -- I also know I don't want to modify $t$ because the integral would only be larger.

Comment: You fixed the $\sin$ and $\cos$ components of $r'(t)$, but the third component is only $\frac{3}{2\pi}$, not $1$, because you only travel $12$ units parallel to the rod's axis while $t$ goes from $0$ to $8\pi$. Replace the $1$ under the square root with the correct $(\frac{3}{2\pi})^2$ and you should get a correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the first "wrap" of the string, and visualize it on an ***unrolled*** cylinder instead of a rod.

The string goes 4 cm sideways, (one circumference), while climbing 3 cm (one quarter of the 12 cm length.

Find the hypotenuse and ...

Useful for designing stairs
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware that we can consider it as a triangle problem but I would like to parametrize the curve.